# Chart.js - is it possible to have data populated as a variable instead of as an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have the following:

```
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type    : 'horizontalBar',
        data    : {
            labels  :  opts.y_axis.line.labels,
            datasets: [
            {
                label           : opts.legend,
                backgroundColor : opts.bg_color,
                borderWidth     : 0,
                data            : opts.data,
             }],},
        options: {
             legend: {
             display: false
             },
             scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                  barPercentage: .8
             }],
             xAxes: [{
                  id: 'A',
                  type: 'linear',
                  position: 'left',
                  ticks: {
                  max: 100,
                  min: 0
                  }
              }]},}})}

              var resp = {
              data      : [65, 59, 60, 81, 56, 76],
              legend    : 'Test Horizontal Bar',
              bg_color  : 'blue',
              y_axis    : {
              line    : {
              labels  : ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
              }},}
```

Is there a way to have data be a variable?  Something like the following:

```
   var theData = [65, 59, 60, 81, 56, 76];
   .
   .
   .
   data: theData,
```

I am using AngularJS and Chart.js to display a horizontal bar graph.  I need to populate the data to be displayed from http calls, so I cannot hard code the data.  I am new to JS and UI work.  I am currently using Chart.js but am willing to use something else.  I have been searching for a way to do this and have been unsuccessful thus far.  Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to assign variables to the `labels`, the dataset items (i.e. `label` and `data`) as well as to individual `options`.

Comment: @uminder can you provide an example?

Comment: You can do exactly what you suggested in your original post, with an array variable `theData`.  If you're having trouble with that, you'll have to provide a test case.

Comment: @ty. thank you.  I got it to work.  I needed to declare the variable in a different location.